# Headless webdriver tests. Unable to use xvfb in java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run headless webdriver tests in java. When I try to run the webdriver test using :1 display, it gives me error

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:30300): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :1


(process:30308): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :1

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at timnow.main(timnow.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 

(process:30300): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :1

(process:30308): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :1

Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'santhu-personal', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.8.0-35-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at timnow.main(timnow.java:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:30300): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :1

(process:30308): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :1

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 6 more
```

Following is my code to get wd instance

```
    String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
    System.out.println(Xport);
    final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", 
        "/usr/bin/firefox"));
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
    firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);

    FirefoxDriver wd;
    wd = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

I am able to run the tests with out xvfb though. I did some research regarding the problem. Some people seemed to have solved the issue with upgrading webdriver but I am using latest webdriver jars ie 2.41.0 with firefox version 26.0

Comment: And is Xvfb really running on display :1 ? e.g. what do you get if you run 
    `ps -ef | grep Xvfb`
on the machine where the tests are supposed to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the mistake of not running xvfb and once I started it as separate process, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

just try to run it like one process:

```
xvfb-run -a java -jar your_jar.jar
```