# How to run headless mode in java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, headless

I am running test in java selenium test using firefox/chrome driver

I want to run the test in background.

In ruby, i use this gem

```
https://rubygems.org/gems/headless
```

How to do in java?

Comment: See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741517/headless-webdriver-tests-unable-to-use-xvfb-in-java) for running Java in xvfb (which is what the ruby headless gem uses)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Firefox headless mode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode

There is an example of how to use it in Node.js

One would think that would translate over to Java quite well. I'm going to give it a shot.

Comment: Worked great. As of now, on Linux you still do need gtk3 in order to use it... but you no longer need XVFB.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is using the [HtmlUnitDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) which based on HtmlUnit project which "GUI less browser".

```
//create webdriver
 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```